# Check file naming convention by custom pattern

Tags: vb.net

I will be having lot of files coming in to to my server and have to check that the filenames match the agreed conventions. I am looking for a way to check for certain patterns. For example:

```
SIR 2016-12.xlsx
Silnik_5_30_cos_26122017.xlsx
DIDO 24_05_2017.xlsx
OMO 12-30.csv
MOK 5_3_17.csv
'others unknown file naming conventions at the moment
```

From what I know, the dynamic part will be always be a date for each files (the difference could be with format of date/datetime/time). What I think I need is to have a config file and declare expected patterns for each of the files using brackets for dynamic date/datetime/time as follows:

```
'within <> are dynamic part

    RTO TR <YYYY-MM>.xlsx           
    Engine-FR_<YYYY_MM_DD>.csv      
    SIR <YYYY-MM>.xlsx
    Silnik_5_30_cos_<DDMMYYYY>.xlsx
    DIDO <DD_MM_YYYY>.xlsx
    OMO <hh-mm>.csv
    MOK <d_M_YY>.csv
```

Afterwords have "universal checker" which could check/decode a specific incoming filename and see if it matches the agreed conventions. What could you propose and how you would accomplish that. Examples appreciated. If possible not using regular expression. Note that I am not aware about all different incoming files as it will be coming on project step therefore good to have solution opened for new filenames.

Comment: Do you have any sway over what the conventions will be? It would be a bit easier if, say, the date part always came last. I suppose it is too much to hope that the date could also be in the file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to check for a specific date format, and the format can include additional characters. You could use that to check for the filename formats.

To do that, you will need to create an array of [DateTime Custom Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) that describe the valid formats. It is likely that you will need to surround the non-date parts of your expected format with single quotes to avoid them being seen as format characters (e.g. to avoid the "M" in "MOK" being seen as the 'month' formatting character.

The following code creates an array with two of your example formats. There are two functions:

- Use the `ValidateFormat` function if you only want to know if the
  filename matches any of the valid formats.
- Use the `FindFormat` function if you need to know **which** valid format the filename matched.

Both functions return the date that was found in the filename.

Private formats() As String = {"'SIR 'yyyy-MM'.xlsx'", "'MOK 'd_M_yy' bu.csv'", "Ala", "'BRT-GH 'yyyy-MM"}

```
''' <summary>Check whether an input string is in one of the valid formats</summary>
''' <param name="input">The string to be checked</param>
''' <param name="dt">If the function returns True, this variable contains the date and time from the input string</param>
''' <returns>True if the input string matches any of the expected formats</returns>
Function ValidateFormat(input As String, ByRef dt As DateTime) As Boolean
    Return DateTime.TryParseExact(TextBox1.Text, formats, 
                                  Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                  Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dt)
End Function

''' <summary>Find which of the valid formats is matched by the input string</summary>
''' <param name="input">The string to be checked</param>
''' <param name="dt">If the function returns True, this variable contains the date and time from the input string</param>
''' <returns>True if the input string matches any of the expected formats</returns>
Function FindFormat(input As String, ByRef dt As DateTime) As String
    For Each format As String In formats
        If DateTime.TryParseExact(TextBox1.Text, format, 
                                  Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                  Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dt) Then Return format
    Next
    Return ""
End Function
```

**[Edit]**
As an example of how to use the functions, here are the methods that I used to test them. They both assume that you type the filename you want to check in `TextBox1`, and they show the result in `TextBox2`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As DateTime
    TextBox2.Text = If(ValidateFormat(TextBox1.Text, dt), dt.ToString, "Error")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dt As DateTime
    TextBox2.Text = FindFormat(TextBox1.Text, dt)
End Sub
```

Comment: can you show example of your functions usage? As i understand i place filename into textbox1.text control and that should be only this, what is for dt and input parameter as well?

Comment: @Arie I added usage examples to my answer. Obviously they are just for demo purposes, your processing is likely to be different.

Comment: seems that function could be used in my case: FindFormat. Regarding second function just recognize whether is datetime and retreive value, however in next step i have to read date part e.g in case of SIR 2016-12.xlsx i have to take only year and month instead of full datetime because there is no time in the filename. In my config i would need to somehow tell if FindFormat is correct (your function will say that) then to get two parts of this date in this case and i have no idea how to solve that. What do you think? Especially that various filenames contains diffrent date time parts

Comment: @Arie You will see that in the usage examples, I define a DateTime value called `dt`. After calling `FindFormat`, dt will contain the date/time from the filename. If only part of the date is specified, the rest will default (so 2016-12 will get you 12:00 AM on 1 December 2016).

Comment: what if there will be really 12:00 AM and 1st day? :)

Comment: @Arie If the format includes a day and a time, they will be reflected in `dt`. For example "MOK 5_3_17.csv" would give you 12:00 AM on 5 March 2017 (because the format string specified d_m_yy).

Comment: can you explain easly what is it for: Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture and Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None

Comment: If you read the [documentation of DateTime.TryParseExact on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx), you will see that the third argument is a CultureInfo object (e.g. enUS, enUK, etc.) and the fourth is a DateTimeStyles value. I used the applications current culture and no styles value. The documentation describes what those values are.

Comment: We have drifted rather far from the original question and we are likely to be told soon that comments are not for extended discussions. I assume the server will be set up with an appropriate culture, so `CurrentCulture` is likely okay. If you don't see any values you need in the documentation of DateTimeStyles, then stick with `None`.

Comment: one more things: sometimes i will receive file which doesnt have any datetime do be checked but only particural text e.g "Ala" i saw that FindFormat" found it, but ValidateFormat gave me:  4/6/2016 12:00:00 AM why?

Comment: If the format doesn't include any date specifiers, the date will default to today.

Comment: why then for particrual name "ala" i get 4/7/2016 12:00:00 AM? And second question why you using apostrof in strings ( i tried to add new one format : "'BRT-GH 'yyyy-MM''" but when trying to filter seems something is wrong and no results why? Did i set this format wrong?

Comment: As I said earlier, if the format contains no date/time specifiers, you will get the current date (which I assume is 7 April on your current server). In the answer, I explain that it is best to surround the fixed part of the format (everything except the format specifiers) in single quotes to make sure they are not mistaken for format specifiers.

Comment: can you explain why when i surround new format like this: 'BRT-GH 'yyyy-MM and when i send value: BRT-GH 2016-12 seems not to work

Comment: @Arie it works for me. All your other examples include an extension (e.g. '.xlsx'). Did you miss the extension in either the format string or the filename that you tested.

Comment: @Arie I have updated the answer to include to two formats you say you are having trouble with. They both work for me. If I enter either **Ala** or **BRT-GH 2016-12** in TextBox1, Both function recognise them.

Comment: you were right i used YYYY instead of yyyy ... My bad. The only one i would love to have is to know what was the date format in file for instance i would like to get yyyy-MM for BRT-GH. Any idea how to get that?